# Составление СЛАУ

Tags: c++

Ребят, помогите разобраться. Пытаюсь составить систему уравнений, чтобы можно было решить методом Гаусса

```
void algorithm(int a,int b,int p)
{
    vector<int> vector1(3);
    vector<int> vector2(3);
    vector1[0] = 2;
    vector1[1] = 3;
    vector1[2] = 5;

    int **mas = new int *[vector1.size()];
    //delete[] mas;
    for (int i = 0; i<vector1.size(); i++)
        mas[i] = new int[vector1.size()];
    int r = 0;
    int e = vector1.size()-1;
    int s = 1;
    int c = 0;
    int t = 1;
//обнуление массива
    for (int i = 0; i <vector1.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <vector1.size()+1; j++)
            mas[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
    {
        r = powmod(a,s,p);//здесь считаем число
        mas[i][vector1.size()] = s;
        while (e!=-1)//раскладываем его на уравение
        {
            if (r%vector1[e] == 0)
            {
                r /= vector1[e];
                mas[i][e]++;
            }
            else
                e--;
        }



     if (r != 1)//проверка, что число полностью разложилось
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < vector1.size(); j++)
                 mas[i][j]=0;
             i--;
         }
    }
```

Как правильно проверять уравнения, чтобы в конечном итоге получилась линейно независимая система?
Я тут подумал уравнения тут будут линейно зависимые(6,36)т.е 36=6^2. Надо наверное, ка-то это проверять
[image: СЛАУ]

Comment: Это уже 4 повтор этого вопроса.

Comment: Все никак придумать не могу как решить